# Python Tracer Array

Tags: python, arrays, string, trace

I have the following problem: I want to Trace only outgoing packets and I have no idea how to sort them out. I want to save them to text file as well, "on the fly" or after I break compiling.
Can anyone help? This is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#Packet sniffer in python
#For Linux - Sniffs all incoming and outgoing packets :)

import socket, sys
from struct import *
from Tkinter import *

#Convert a string of 6 characters of ethernet address into a dash separated  hex string
ef eth_addr (a) :
  b = "%.2x:%.2x:%.2x:%.2x:%.2x:%.2x" % (ord(a[0]) , ord(a[1]) , ord(a[2]),     ord(a[3]), ord(a[4]) , ord(a[5]))
  return b

#create a AF_PACKET type raw socket (thats basically packet level)
#define ETH_P_ALL    0x0003          /* Every packet (be careful!!!) */
try:
    s = socket.socket( socket.AF_PACKET , socket.SOCK_RAW ,     socket.ntohs(0x0003))
except socket.error , msg:
    print 'Socket could not be created. Error Code : ' + str(msg[0]) + ' Message ' + msg[1]
    sys.exit()

# receive a packet
while True:
    packet = s.recvfrom(65565)

    #packet string from tuple
    packet = packet[0]

    #parse ethernet header
    eth_length = 14

    eth_header = packet[:eth_length]
    eth = unpack('!6s6sH' , eth_header)
    eth_protocol = socket.ntohs(eth[2])

    #Parse IP packets, IP Protocol number = 8
    if eth_protocol == 8 :
        #Parse IP header
        #take first 20 characters for the ip header
        ip_header = packet[eth_length:20+eth_length]

        #now unpack them :)
        iph = unpack('!BBHHHBBH4s4s' , ip_header)

        version_ihl = iph[0]
        version = version_ihl >> 4
        ihl = version_ihl & 0xF

        iph_length = ihl * 4

        ttl = iph[5]
        protocol = iph[6]
        s_addr = socket.inet_ntoa(iph[8]);
        d_addr = socket.inet_ntoa(iph[9]);


        print ' Source Address : ' + str(s_addr) + ' Destination Address : ' + str(d_addr)
```